# Opencart - Way to call ajax request in Admin Panel

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I want to fetch some data using ajax request in Opencart Admin panel. I have simply created a controller which only returns data in json format. Using below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?route=common/ajaxdata/functionName&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        if (json['success']) {
            alert(json['success']);
        }
    }
 });
```

Can anybody please let know whether this is correct or any other built in functionality available in Opencart for ajax requests? So that I can proceed and implement this in my rest of the pages.

Thanks

Comment: if you try your code and it works, it's correct.  if it doesn't work, it's not correct.  have you tried it?  what happened when you did?  what problem are you having? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://your url write hare",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "propertytypename": property,
        "propertytypecreatedby": property_name
    }),
    success: alert("success"),
    error: alert("Fail")

});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.